# MAC: Qt Cannot detect toolkit

Tags: c++, macos, qt, gcc

[image: Screen]

How I can configure QT Project using Qt 5.12.1/Qt Creator 4.8.1
I need compile my project for mac os.
I tryed with QT Creator, then, below problem occur.

Or compile with below command.

```
qmake
make
```

But, below error is occur.

```
third_party/wfdbio.cpp:181:5: fatal error: assigning to 'char *' from
      incompatible type 'void *'
    SSTRCPY(wfdbpath, wfdbpath_init);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
third_party/wfdb.h:234:3: note: expanded from macro 'SSTRCPY'
         SALLOC(P, (size_t)strlen(WFDB_tmp)+1,1); strcpy(P, WFDB_tmp); } }
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
third_party/wfdb.h:231:37: note: expanded from macro 'SALLOC'
#define SALLOC(P, N, S) { SFREE(P); SUALLOC(P, (N), (S)) }
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
third_party/wfdb.h:230:38: note: expanded from macro 'SUALLOC'
#define SUALLOC(P, N, S) { if (!(P = calloc((N), (S)))) MEMERR(P, (N), (S)); }
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [objects/wfdbio.o] Error 1
```

[image: Error Screen2]
Of course, I can change some code with typecast, ex.) `char* to void*`.
But, there are many macros, and codes, so, many code change is need for "remove type cast".
Of course, I used "-fpermissive" flags, and my project is compiled at Windows 10.

So, How I can compile my project without code change?

**EDIT:**

Here is a MRE of my problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
int main()
{
    char *buffer;

    printf("How long do you want the string? ");

    buffer = malloc(10);
    // buffer = (char* ) malloc(10);

    return 0;
}
```

This code is compiled at Windows10 [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/).

```
# At Cygwin, gcc version is
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-pc-cygwin
Configured with: /cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/gcc/gcc-7.4.0-1.x86_64/src/gcc-7.4.0/configure --srcdir=/cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/gcc/gcc-7.4.0-1.x86_64/src/gcc-7.4.0 --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --localstatedir=/var --sysconfdir=/etc --docdir=/usr/share/doc/gcc --htmldir=/usr/share/doc/gcc/html -C --build=x86_64-pc-cygwin --host=x86_64-pc-cygwin --target=x86_64-pc-cygwin --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --libexecdir=/usr/lib --enable-shared --enable-shared-libgcc --enable-static --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-bootstrap --enable-__cxa_atexit --with-dwarf2 --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=ada,c,c++,fortran,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-graphite --enable-threads=posix --enable-libatomic --enable-libcilkrts --enable-libgomp --enable-libitm --enable-libquadmath --enable-libquadmath-support --disable-libssp --enable-libada --disable-symvers --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --with-cloog-include=/usr/include/cloog-isl --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --with-system-zlib --enable-linker-build-id --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=gcc4-compatible --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.4.0 (GCC)
```

But, I cannot compile at My Mac OS.

> Below is error code.

```
Ws-Mac:Desktop w$ gcc test.cpp -fpermissive
test.cpp:9:14: error: assigning to 'char *' from incompatible type 'void *'
    buffer = malloc(10);
             ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

```
# At Mac OS, gcc version is
Ws-Mac:Desktop w$ gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
Ws-Mac:Desktop w$
```

Comment: This looks less like a Qt/Qt Creator issue to me, probably your code just doesn’t compile with clang and needs to be fixed.

Comment: Actually it should not have compiled in Windows too. The issue is not about Qt. `calloc()` returns a `void*`. I'm not sure C++ allows to assign a `void*` to a `char*` without type casting. IMHO, you should `static_cast<char*>` the return type of your `calloc()` calls.

Comment: @Fareanor Yes, you are right, in fact this problem is of `-fpermissive`. At windows, `-fpermissive` is working, but at mac os, not working.

Comment: I want `-fpermissive` is working at Mac os

Comment: please show a [mre] with the code that isn't compiling and where you are adding the `-fpermissive` to the compiler command line

Comment: I updated question as @Alan Birtles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to a difference in how C and C++ handle conversions to a from a `void *`.  In C, any pointer type may freely be converted to/from a `void *` without a cast.  C++ does not allow this, and will throw an error if you attempt to convert without a cast.

The code in your example is C code but the filename ends in .cpp, so gcc compiles the code as C++.  So this line:

```
buffer = malloc(10);
```

generates an error because C++ doesn't allow an implicit `void *` conversion.

If you changed the filename from test.cpp to test.c it will compile cleanly.

Going back to your QT project, since QT is a C++ library you can't just attempt to compile all of the code as C code.

If the modules that have these errors contain **only** C code then you can change the filename of those modules from .cpp to .c, and you'll need to modify the associated header files to add `extern "C"` around the declarations of the functions.  If these errors appear in modules that actually are C++, then you need to change your code to use `static_cast<char*>` to assign the return value of `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc` to a `char *`.

Comment: Thanks @dbush, I tried "change cpp -> c". of course this working on MAC OS. But, my qt project is compiled at windows. of course, i solved my problem with this answer

Comment: But, at window10, my before project is compiled although cpp

Comment: @KingStone on windows you were using gcc which has an option to allow implicit casts from `void*` (-fpermissive), clang has no such option

Comment: with gcc, we can compile cpp file?

Comment: @KingStone Yes, gcc will compile .c files as C and will compile .cpp files as C++.  There is also g++ which only compiles as C++.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is "don't use `malloc` in c++", if you use `new` instead the problem goes away and as a bonus you correctly initialise classes.

If you really must use `malloc` you can't avoid the need to `static_cast` the result into the appropriate type.

If you really don't want to add static casts everywhere then something like this might work:

```
struct mymalloc
{
    mymalloc(size_t size)
    : data(malloc(size))
    {
    }
    mymalloc(const mymalloc&) = delete;
    mymalloc& operator=(const mymalloc&) = delete;

    void* data;

    template <typename T>
    operator T*()
    {
        return static_cast<T*>(data);
    }
};

int main()
{
    char *buffer = mymalloc(10);
    free(buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

You might even have some success with `#define malloc mymalloc` but you'd need to be very careful not to break anything else by doing that.

I repeat though that the proper solution is to switch from `malloc` to `new` and avoid all this hackery.